System keyboard not appearing when using XR Interaction Toolkit raycasting with TMP InputField in Unity VR
I'm encountering an issue in my Unity project where VR immersive view mode is enabled, and I'm utilizing raycasting with XR Interaction Toolkit to interact with a TextField (TMP InputField). While raycasting functions properly with buttons and dropdowns, upon focusing on the TMP InputField and pressing the trigger or index button of my controller, the system keyboard fails to appear. Is there something I might be overlooking?

If you use oculus, you can add this to the manifest
<uses-feature android:name="oculus.software.overlay_keyboard" android:required="true" />

